# VSCode SSH to remote - node: not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

SSH from VSCode (Mac) to a remote host (Raspberry Pi) stopped working a while ago.
I have searched the web for solutions, but whatever I did - I was unable to solve the issue.

I tried `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server` and then connect again - It did not work.
Also, I tried setting `"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false` which also did not help.
Another thing I've tried is to install an older version of the SSH extension in VSCode - it did not help.

Not sure if related, but I have Fig (https://fig.io/) installed on my Mac.

Here's the log from VSCode:

```
 > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898.log >>>
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898/bin/code-server: 12: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898/bin/code-server: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898/node: not found
> <<< End of server log
> 911ac96db1fc: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==raspbian==
> arch==aarch64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime==5371==
> installTime==3172==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==7728==
> 911ac96db1fc: end
[09:55:56.941] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==aarch64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime==5371==
installTime==3172==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==7728==
```

Checking the log I see "node: not found", so I checked the directory and confirmed that indeed the file exists there.

Can someone please assist with troubleshooting steps for this?
Thanks ahead.

EDIT: I was able to solve that following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6388#issuecomment-1050923254 which mentioned to change the `arm_64bit` to 0.
Hope that helps whoever might encounter this.

Comment: I was able to solve that following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6388#issuecomment-1050923254 which mentioned to change the arm_64bit to 0. Hope that helps whoever might encounter this.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel solved his own question:

> I was able to solve that following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6388#issuecomment-1050923254 which mentioned to change the arm_64bit to 0. Hope that helps whoever might encounter this.

However the answer still leaves some guesswork. So here the details which fixed if for me:

1. Add the new entry `arm_64bit=0` to the file /boot/config.txt on the Raspberry.
2. Remove the existing vscode files using `sudo rm -r .vscode*`

The next reconnection from VSCode was successful.

Comment: From the raspberry pi docs : If set to 1, the kernel will be started in 64-bit mode. Setting to 0 selects 32-bit mode. Also this option is removed from the raspberry pi 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing this package on the server!

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:amd64
```

or adding the path of the library If the libstdc++.so.6 library is in the location /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6, you can add the following line to the end of the .bashrc file in your home directory

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

To edit the .bashrc file, you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then, to apply the changes, you can run the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then,

***I resolved it in the following steps.***

**

1. Access remote server.
2. Remove or rename /home/{username}/.vscode-server/bin.
3. Update Remote-SSH Extensión (v0.101.2023032915 )
4. Reload Visual Studio Code Try SSH-Remote

**

[image]

Comment: I apologize in advance, I'm new to this, in the edit you can find the solution to the question