# VSCode : node : file not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this error when connecting to a remote server with SSH and VSCode

```
/home/somedir/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f
> 0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node : file not found
```

I looked into the existing solutions, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823972/vscode-ssh-to-remote-node-not-found)

But it does not work for me, because 1) I am not using a Raspeberry but a simple Linux 2) I cannot install anything using apt-get

So I am wondering: is there a way, for instance using symbolic links, to make linux understand that the node file is actually where it does not find it ?

Thanks